# Which level should I make for this condition method extracted from somewhere?

Tags: c++, refactoring

If I have a method belongs to class A, and the logic I want to extract is most all about public method of class B. Where should I extract this logic into?

- A's private method?

  reason: it is extracted from A's method.
- B's public method?

  reason: it describes class B's state.
- free function?

  reason: it does not need access B's private member.
- or it is always depends?

example:

The code need to be refactored:

```
class Cat
{public:
    void eat(const CatFood& cf)
    {
        if(!cf.expired() && cf.flavor() == CatFood::Flavor::Tuna)
           std::cout << "Cat has eaten food." << std::endl;
        else
           std::cout << "Cat is hungry and still meow meow." << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Version 1: A's private method

```
class Cat
{public:
     void eat(const CatFood& cf)
     {
         if(can_eat(cf))
           std::cout << "Cat has eaten food." << std::endl;
        else
           std::cout << "Cat is hungry and still meow meow." << std::endl; 
     }

 private:
     bool can_eat(const CatFood& cf) const
     { 
         return !cf.expired() && cf.flavor() == CatFood::Flavor::Tuna;
     };
}
```

Version 2: B's public method

```
Cat Cat
{public:
     void eat(const CatFood& cf)
     {
        if(cf.eatable_with_flavor(CatFood::Flavor::Tuna))
           std::cout << "Cat has eaten food." << std::endl;
        else
           std::cout << "Cat is hungry and still meow meow." << std::endl; 
     }
}

class Catfood
{
 public:
     bool eatable_with_flavor(CatFood::Flavor specific_flavor) const
     { 
         return !expired() && flavor() == specific_flavor;
     };

     bool expired(){...}
}
```

Version 3: Free function

```
Cat Cat
{public:
     void eat(const CatFood& cf)
     {
        if(eatable_with_flavor(cf, CatFood::Flavor::Tuna))
           std::cout << "Cat has eaten food." << std::endl;
        else
           std::cout << "Cat is hungry and still meow meow." << std::endl; 
     }
}

bool eatable_with_flavor(const CatFood& cf, CatFood::Flavor specific_flavor)
{ 
    return !cf.expired() && cf.flavor() == specific_flavor;
};
```

I always do the version 1, because it happens in the class A, and just simply extract the codes next to original one. And I think the logic I extracted is only describing class B's state, it could be better to put into class B. After that, I observed the code in new method only invoke B's public methods, it could be better to put it into a free function. I was told the only reason make the function to be a member function is you need to access the class's private member, or you should make it to be a free function.

These three version looks has its reasons. Could anyone give me a suggestion or point out where I am wrong.

btw: Should I write a test for this condition method? Because it looks so trivial. But I know it is a good habit to make as many as possible functions under test.

Comment: As per [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97640/should-programming-best-practices-be-on-stackoverflow-or-programmers-se), I would recommend posting this sort of question in [programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a beautiful example of the ever re-occuring question: [Composition or inheritance?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Since `isEatable` is currently only dependent on `CatFood` it would be the most natural decision to put it into `CatFood`. However, the really interesting questions (and thus answers) tend to arise when you start asking: Where will I go next? What if you want to add a a `Dog` and `DogFood`, possibly inheriting from the same base classes as `Cat` and `CatFood`? What if then `isEatable` might suddenly depend on the `Animal` that wants to eat it (in my own experience, age, for example, plays a big role in this decision)? After considering these kinds of questions, you can choose the one that observes least coupling and possibly other benefits, or...

You go with your gut on this one, and focus on all the other issues that you will have to face before your code reaches production. :)